# How do I "parse" image locations on a minimap with OpenCV (or other tool)?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I've been trying to work on a small hobby project that involves plotting players' positions from a game onto a heatmap, to see where the most active areas are at various points in time.

I'm a bit new to OpenCV and its tools, but I've managed to successfully run some text matching and extraction on the scoreboard and timers in the game, now trying to take the characters' positions from the in-game minimap.

It looks like this, which is the biggest resolution image I'm able to get with (about 185x185):

[image]

I'm trying to obtain the positions of only two things: the characters (big circles) and "wards", which are represented by these icons:

[image][image][image]

So given the assets to them, I thought that because there was too much "noise" in the source image, I'd try to subtract the background of in game minimap from its image, and then try to pattern match the original character and ward image with the resulting image together (which is meant to be the minimap, minus its background). But that didn't even get close to working as you can see:

[image] > [image] > [image]

Even if that did work, I wouldn't be really sure how to handle cases where the icons are partially covering each other, or how I could obtain the positions of those little ward markers.

I'd really appreciate some help, as I've been searching the Internet and banging my head for a few days and haven't gotten anywhere. I've tried a bunch of difference techniques, read guides and articles, and tried a few GUI tools to experiment with but haven't gotten any closer to a method to work this out.

Please help me with what techniques I could or should be using instead, to get the locations of all the characters and wards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an OpenCV user, but I can speak to some general problems.

First and foremost, you goofed in subtracting the background map.  It appears that you did a straight, arithmetic subtraction of the map's RGB values.  For instance, the blue-team icons in the lower-left corner are roughly #99FFFF, and you're subtracting the grayish background of maybe #D0D0FF.  This leaves you with #002F00, a very dark green.

Also note that you're subtracting the *original* map, not the part that shows.  Paths beyond view are shaded, but you appear to subtract the original value.

What you need to subtract is a masked background.  Unfortunately, building that mask means that you have to find the icons.  Masking won't work well at this stage.

Back to the subtraction: don't just blindly subtract.  Rather, look for a match in hue.  When you find a hue match, simply set that pixel to 0.  You have two special cases to watch: icons on the background of their own colour, especially for the blue team.  In this case, you need to define the region boundaries.

Start from a pixel that's an exact match to the original background.  It won't be shaded, since all such problem pixels are in plain sight of an icon.  Expand from that pixel so long as you have the exact match to the original background colour.  That will give you the region you can blank out.

---

Your next problem is to identify icons.  You should now have a map with only icons, many of which are fully revealed.  Those are easy matches; identify and subtract them, one key icon at a time.

You now have a map of partial icons.  Switch the match algorithm: a key icon is now a match to either the exact color, *or* to black (indicating it was previously covered).  Iterate until you have no more matches.

---

This *does* still leave you with one problem: an icon that no longer has enough pixels showing to identify.  These will be icons that were either entirely covered, or covered except for a small portion that is not unique, such as a few pixels of a red circular border.

For this, a general approach is to keep track of game progress to a small extent: from an earlier time, you know where the icon *used* to be.  Track each icon as a software object.  If other icons cover it, assume it's still there until you discover otherwise.

This will handle most cases.  You'll still have some problems with minions or sensors that get shot out from underneath a legend's icon, but I trust that your heat map application is not so fragile as to take modelling damage from that situation.  The legend will move soon enough, revealing the small item's death.  A moving minion isn't covered by a legend for long; they don't move with the same intelligence.